# Go Template variable check not behaving as I expected

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a few nested structs passed to my go html template.I want to check if a slice is empty and print "No Data" if its empty.

I'm doing this with the following template code, but I never prints empty , it just donesnt  render any html. I've put text around the value to see if its outputting my text with empty but its not rendering my text. I thought there could be some other tests I need to so on the $s below , suchs $s not nil or $s not "". I've tried those but get the same result. I have noticed that if I print `{{$dr.Swells}}` before the range I get []. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
{{ range $d := .DailyHtmlData}}
  <div class="row"><small><br></br></small></div>  

        {{range $dr := $d.Forecast}}
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-2 text-left nopadding"><small>{{$dr.Day}}/{{$dr.Month}} {{$dr.Hour}}:00</small></div>
             {{range $s := $dr.Swells}}
               {{if  $s }}
                  <div class="row"><small>
                    <div class="col col-auto text-left nopadding">{{$s.Dir}} {{$s.Height}}ft@{{$s.Period}}Sec |</div> 
                  </small></div>
               {{else}}
                  <div class="row"><small>
                    <div>No Data.</div>
                  </small></div>
             {{end}}
            {{end}}
        <div class="col text-right nopadding"><small>Wind:{{$dr.Winddir}}:{{$dr.Windspd}}mph Gusts:{{$dr.Windgus}}</small></div>
       </div>
        {{end}}
   {{end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{{range pipeline}} T1 {{else}} T0 {{end}}` form to print something when the slice is empty or nil.

```
         {{range $s := $dr.Swells}}
              <div class="row"><small>
                <div class="col col-auto text-left nopadding">{{$s.Dir}} {{$s.Height}}ft@{{$s.Period}}Sec |</div> 
              </small></div>
         {{else}}
              <div class="row"><small>
                <div>No Data.</div>
              </small></div>
         {{end}}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, does that mean that $s is not set if nil or empty ? it just moves to the next item in the slice ?

Comment: The range clause is executed for each element in `$dr.Swells`.  If there are no elements in `$dr.Swells` (because it is nil or length is zero), then the else clause is executed.